What do we know about the computable surreal numbers?
The surreal numbers are built up in a natural iterative process, by which at any ordinal stage, if one has two sets of surreal numbers $L$ and $R$, with every number $x_L$ in $L$ strictly below every number $x_R$ in $R$, then one creates if necessary a new surreal number situated between them, filling this gap.

$$x=\{L\mid R\}$$
This also defines the order recursively. In general, we define a notion of equivalence, with the effect that all numbers created at a given stage filling the same gap in the earlier numbers are equal and $\{L\mid R\}$ denotes the first-born such number filling that gap. But there is also a canonical representation of every number, which avoids the need for the equivalence relation, where the $L$ and $R$ sets form a partition of the previously-created numbers. This canonical representation can be seen as essentially identical to the representation of surreals by binary $\{-1,1\}$ transfinite sequences, where a $1$ means move up from the preceding number and $-1$ means move down from it.
My question is about the restriction of the construction to what I shall call the computable surreal numbers.
Namely, let's simply define by recursion that a Turing machine program $e$ is a computable surreal number with value $\alpha_e$ if running program $e$ produces two enumerations—for simplicity let's use a multitape model with two output tapes—such that all the numbers appearing in the enumeration are programs that are themselves computable surreal numbers, and furthermore the values obey $\alpha_x<\alpha_y$ whenever $x$ appears on the first output tape and $y$ appears on the second output tape. In this case, the value of $e$ is
$$\alpha_e = \{\ \alpha_x\mid\alpha_y\ \},$$
where $x$ and $y$ range respectively over the numbers appearing in the first and second enumerations produced by $e$.
For example, the program that produces the empty sequence on each side will be a computable representation of the surreal number $0=\{\ \mid\ \}$. And then one can produce programs to produce $1=\{0\mid\ \}$ and $-1=\{\ \mid 0\}$, and so forth, in the usual process of building up the surreal numbers.
So ultimately this is a recursive definition of what it means to be a computable surreal number, and one can imagine the definition proceeding in a sequence of transfinite stages. One reaches in effect the smallest fixed-point, the smallest set of programs that fulfills the recursive definition.
One might prefer a representation closer to Kleene's $\cal O$, which would be fine with me, although I also find the recursive definition I gave above to have a clean simplicity.
It is not difficult to see that every computable ordinal, viewed as a surreal number in the obvious manner, will be a computable surreal number. Also, the computable surreal numbers will form an ordered field. It will be countable, of course, and hence not the same as $\text{No}(\omega_1^{CK})$, which is uncountable of size continuum.

Are the computable surreal numbers a real-closed field?

It seems initially clear that they form a field, since we have the formulas for how to define addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division, and if we give these formulas programs that actually are surreal numbers, then (by transfinite induction) they will output programs that give computable surreal numbers. (See also my comment below.) I believe that one can similarly compute square roots of positive elements. I am less sure about every odd-degree polynomial having a root, although I fully expect this to be true.
The answer to the next question might seem obvious:

Which real numbers are computable surreal numbers?

One might initially expect that these should be exactly the computable real numbers. But in light of the computable ordinal nature of the construction, it seems to me that perhaps one gets instead much more: the hyperarithmetic reals. For example, can we design a program that enumerates slightly better bounds on a surreal number according to the halting problem, so that the real number value that it exhibits will encode the halting problem? If so, I expect this to go all the way to the hyperarithmetic reals.

Is the computable surreal field computably saturated?

I am not clear on how to prove that consistent computable types are realized.
Next, it seems to me that the set of computable surreal numbers (considered as a set of programs) will be $\Pi^1_1$-complete, as well as the equality relation $e=f$, and the order relation $e<f$. [Update: the relation $e<f$ is actually c.e. as a I prove in my answer below, and so $e=f$ is co-c.e. Revised update. The proposed proof that $e<f$ is c.e. was incorrect, and it now appears that the relation is complicated, as originally expected.]
For the upper bound, if we have an oracle for $\Pi^1_1$, then given any computable surreal number $e$, we can computably unwrap the underlying hereditary structure of the left and right sets and ask whether this is well-founded. Furthermore, we can ask about the hereditary order and equality on those numbers, which is uniquely determined by the recursion and so this will be $\Delta^1_1$.
For the lower bound, we can canonically interpret any purported computable well order into the surreal number formalism, and thereby reduce the well-foundedness of a linear order to the question whether a given program is a computable surreal number.
What remains are several further questions:

What is the complexity of the same-birthday relation, relating computable surreal numbers with the same birthday?

What is the complexity of the function that maps every computable surreal number $x$ to its canonical representation $\{L\mid R\}$, where $L$ consists of the earlier-born numbers below $x$ and $R$ consists of the earlier-born numbers above $x$?

What is the complexity of the function that maps every computable surreal number $x$ to the transfinite binary representation of $x$?


It seems likely that all these complexities are all $\Pi^1_1$-complete. Is that right? Perhaps same-birthday involves $\Sigma^1_1$, since one needs to match up the earlier birthdays, so this might push the complexity up.
Lastly, I might ask whether there are other accounts of the computable surreal numbers and whether they are different/equivalent to the account I described above.

This is a really nice question, but is it easy to see that the computable surreals are actually closed under the standard field operations? I assume you need to use effective transfinite recursion or something to show this.

I thought the usual definitions of $x+y$ and $-x$ and $x/y$ are computable operations. One writes down formulas for the left and right sets of the resulting real in terms of the input sets, and this provides a means of showing that these numbers remain computable if $x$ and $y$ are. Well-foundedness will be preserved, as well as the hereditary order.  (Unless: do the formulas require us sometimes to check the order relation on hereditary parts of the numbers? If so, this will be too complicated for computable.)

I'll have to think about that. Regarding 2, shouldn't it be fairly immediate that any left (or right) c.e. irrational real is a computable surreal number? Moreover, I think you should get closure under computable infima and suprema (that happen to be irrational) fairly immediately, which should give you all hyperarithmetic reals.

Yes, that seems right, and it is what I was thinking about with the halting problem proposal. My conjecture is that you get exactly the hyperarithmetic reals. Please post an answer explicating this idea, if you would.

Regarding $x+y$, perhaps it helps to say that the defining formulas give us computable procedures for the defining the sum of any programs at all, but when $x$ and $y$ are actually computable surreal numbers, then the resulting output $x+y$ will also be a computable surreal number. So the effective transfinite recursion is in effect sublimated. (But I also want to think this through thoroughly.)

By "earlier born" do you mean "simpler than" (i.e., is a prefix of, in sign-sequence representation) or do you just mean having a lower birthday? I guess both of these yield canonical forms, but I thought the former was the more usual one? I guess could ask about both, or ask about the "simpler than" relation itself perhaps?

Regarding the earlier @JamesEHanson question, looking in detail at the definitions of $x+y$, $x-y$, $x\cdot y$ and $x/y$, it seems in each case we have a recursive formula, which reduces the desired output to one determined by left/right sets with earlier applications of that same function. By Kleene fixed-point theorem, there is a computable process that solves this recursion, and so it seems to me that all of these are computable operations on the computable surreal numbers. So indeed the computable surreal numbers form a field.

@HarryAltman Indeed, by earlier born, I meant that the number was born earlier, that is, that it appeared at an earlier stage of the transfinite construction process. I think of this as the core concept, in light of the gap-filling construction process. But indeed you are right, the prefix relation is very commonly considered. I tried to ask about both of these relations, in questions 5 and 6.

I suspect Lurie's old paper Effective content of surreal algebra will be relevant here, but it's been a while since I looked at it so I can't immediately say if/how it addresses your specific questions here.

@NoahSchweber Thanks very much! He seems to take the binary ordinal sequence approach as primitive (which seems misguided to me), and then observes (by Harkleroad), if I've followed, that you can't add. In this sense, my definition seems better. But I need to look more. (It would be the surreal analogue of Turing's mistake with computable real numbers, to insist we can compute the digits...)

What kind of programs are allowed? I mean, due to the halting problem there could be programs about which we do not know if they denote a number or not...

@Anixx The programs are those that enumerate two sequences of programs, which obey the order condition and which also fulfill the recursive definition. (If they halt, then both sides will be finite, but that is fine, so halting/nonhalting is not necessarily an obstacle, although one expects that interesting surreals will have infinite cuts, so nonhalting.) Nevertheless, as I mention in the post, the decision problem to decide if a program computes a surreal number is $\Pi^1_1$-complete. This is way beyond the halting problem in complexity, and is even beyond what is arithmetically definable.

Is it not clear that if you call $(r_n)$ the dyadic rational whose $k$-th binary digit is $1$ when $k≤n$ and the $k$-th Turing machine halts in less than $n$ steps, and $0$ otherwise, thus defining a Specker sequence, then ${r_n|}$ as a surreal (computable in your sense) equals $\sup(r_n)$ as a real, which is not computable? Your paragraph following question (2) suggests you saw this argument but have at least a little doubt about it: to me it seems convincing, no?

Lean mathlib contains a definition of inductively-defined combinatorial games, but inverse is defined using excluded-middle.

@Gro-Tsen Indeed that is something like what I had in mind. But the construction you propose doesn't quite work in the way you suggest, since any surreal number with an empty upper set will be an ordinal, an integer in this case. (In particular, it is not $\sup(r_n)$.) You have to approach the real from both sides, and this prevents a straightforward implementation of this approximation idea, since you don't computably know the optimal upper bounds.

And this objection might pour cold water on @JamesEHanson's idea about c.e. reals. You can't just approach from one side, since that trivializes in the surreal numeral semantics.

@JamesEHanson Nevertheless, I've realized how to get the c.e. real result. See the update in my answer, below. Every c.e. real is realized as a computable surreal number. I don't see yet, however, how to get effective suprema and infinima in the computable surreals.

You only need odd prime degree polynomials to have roots, not odd degree polynomials, to get real closedness. I prefer the algebra of Conway’s other Field “On2”, consisting of the Ordinals as an underlying Class and defining nim-addition (which is just surreal addition) and nim-multiplication as the Field operations. The first algebraically closed subfield is the ordinal omega^(omega^omega); I’m not sure his problem of identifying the next one was ever solved.

For any $A \subseteq\mathbb{N}$ let $x_A = \sum_{k \in A} 3^{-k}$ and $x_A^{(n)} = \sum_{k \in A, k < n} 3^{-k}$. Given two computably inseparable c.e. sets $A$ and $B$, the surreal ${  { x_A^{(n)} ; n \in \mathbb{N} }  \mid { x_A + x_B^{(n)} ; n \in \mathbb{N} }  }$ should be of some interest. For instance, we shouldn't be able to "squeeze" the left and the right cut together all the way for such a real.

@AndrejBauer Thanks for the suggestion, and I'm glad you're thinking about this. But have you written what you intended? If $A$ is c.e., then $x_A$ is a c.e. real, hence computable surreal by the argument in my answer. And this is the LUB in ℝ of the lower set in your surreal. But the upper set has $x_A$ as an element, for $n=0$, and so only $n=0$ matters there. So your surreal number is $x_A-\varepsilon$, where $\varepsilon={0\mid 2^{-n}}_{n\in ℕ}$ is the first-born infinitesimal, since $x_A-\varepsilon$ is the first-born surreal filling this gap. This is also computable surreal.

Ah, you're quite right. Can we fix this so that the upper set is far away from the lower one, and we can't computably get closer? Maybe $x_A + x_B - x^{(n)}_B$? I am just trting to come up with a qualitatively different example, namely one that has an incompressible gap between the lower and the upper cut.

If there is a gap, then the value will simply be the first-born dyadic rational in between.

@JoelDavidHamkins. Your query "Are the computable surreal numbers a real-closed field?" naturall raises two related queries, since every real-closed field is isomorphic to an initial subfield of No. (1) Is the system of computable surreal numbers initial? (2) Is there precisely one initial copy of the computable surreal numbers in No?

@PhilipEhrlich Given that there are non-computable reals in the computable surreals, there can't only be one copy by a fairly general model-theoretic argument (assuming that by copy we mean copy as a field). This follows because the surreal numbers are a saturated model of RCF.

@PhilipEhrlich Can you remind me what initial means? Does that mean that if something is in, and you take the $+-$ sequence representing it, then all the numbers arising from initial segments of that sequence are in?

@JoelDavidHamkins. Yes. A subtree $A$ of No is initial if for each x in A, the set of predecessors of x in A coincides with the set of predecessors of x in No, where predecessors are understood in the tree-theoretic sense. There are ordered fields that are not real-closed that are isomorphic to initial subfields of No, but by an early result of mine every real-closed field is. I strongly suspect that like the reals, the structure you are concerned with is isomorphic to exactly one initial subfield of No. Initial subfields can be generated by Conway's  definitions applied to the initial tree.

@James E Hansen. I didn't say there might be one isomorphic copy, but rather one initial isomorphic copy. Does your argument rule that out?

@PhilipEhrlich Good, that is what I thought. On Dan's answer, I had suggested the possibility that the computable surreal numbers are exactly the surreals with a hyperarithmetic +- sequence, which would make them initial. I think Dan's idea on the hyperarithmetic reals may generalize to produce this.

I've realized that there is a natural generalization of the computable surreal concept to the general concept of a (generalized) c.e. set. Namely, if a program enumerates a list of programs that are generalized c.e., then so is the program itself, and the set it represents is the set whose elements are represented by the programs it has enumerated. So every computable ordinal is generalized c.e., and the generalized c.e. sets are hyperarithmetically presentable. Are they exactly the sets in $L_{\omega_1^{CK}}$?

@PhilipEhrlich I think not. My argument is just for the algebraic field structure, and it seems like you're talking about the tree structure.

Dan has now proved that the computable surreals are those with a hyperarithmetic sign sequence, and so indeed they form an initial subfield. The computable surreals are exactly the surreals in $L_{\omega_1^{CK}}$, and from this, I believe it follows that they are real-closed.

@James E Hanson. Then we agree.

I have now asked that generalized c.e. set question https://mathoverflow.net/q/473684/1946. I call them the hereditarily computably enumerable sets.

@NoahSchweber It seems that in addition to that account with computable binary sequences, Lurie's paper also has an account of the computable surreals that follow my proposal here, and he made the connection with $L_{\omega_1}^{CK}$ and so forth. Much of what has been observed on this question and its answers also already appears in that paper.

The reals which are computable surreals are precisely the hyperarithmetical reals, as you conjectured.  I'll be making use of your argument that the field operations are effective (really just addition and subtraction, and the fact that we know how to create notations for $2^{-n}$).
In the one direction, every computable surreal notation has a rank $\alpha$, which is a computable ordinal.  By induction (actually effective transfinite recursion), the corresponding real is computable from something like $0^{(2\alpha+1)}$.

In the other direction, I first claim that for any computable ordinal $\alpha$, from a $\Sigma^c_\alpha$ sentence we can uniformly obtain a notation which corresponds to $0$ if the sentence is false and $1$ if the sentence is true.  Again this is effective transfinite recursion masquerading as induction.  You already did the base case in your example of $\alpha_h$.
For the inductive step, if $\phi$ is $\Sigma^c_\alpha$, then $\phi = \bigvee_n \theta_n$, where the $\theta_n$ are all $\Pi^c_{<\alpha}$.  Let $b_n$ be from the inductive hypothesis applied to $\neg \theta_n$.  Then $\{ 0-b_n : n \in \omega \ | \ 2 \}$ is as desired for $\phi$.
Now let $x$ be some hyperarithmetical real.  WLOG, $0 < x < 1$.  We wish to give a notation.  If $x$ is a dyadic rational, the result is immediate.  Otherwise, there is some computable $\alpha$ such that for $q$ a dyadic rational and $n \in \omega$, "$x \in (q, q+2^{-n})$" is $\Sigma^c_\alpha$.  For each dyadic rational $q \in (0, 1)$ and $n \in \omega$, let $b_{q, n}$ be as from the previous claim for this sentence.  Then $x = \{ q +b_{q,n} - 1 : q, n \ | \ q + 2^{-n} + 1 - b_{q,n} : q, n\}$.
Edit: Thinking further, I don't need to handle the case that $x$ is dyadic separately.  Everything I wrote after that is still true in that case.

Reciprocals. Note that if $y \neq 0$ is hyperarithmetic, then so is $1/y$.  From this, it follows that if $y \neq 0$ is real and a computable surreal, then $1/y$ is also a computable surreal.
The process is mostly uniform: going from a hyperarithmetic real to a computable surreal real required a prior bounds (0 and 1 in my above writeup, but any computable bounds would have sufficed).  So it will be uniformly computable if also given a rational bound away from 0: a rational $q$ with $|y| > q > 0$.  Then we can use $-1/q < 1/y < 1/q$ as our bounds.
This is an example of a phenomenon known as level computability.  The domain is an increasing union of sets, $\bigcup_n U_n$, where $U_n = (-\infty, -2^{-n}) \cup (2^{-n}, \infty)$.  The function (reciprocal) is uniformly computable if in addition to being given a $y$ from the domain, it is also given an $n$ with $y \in U_n$.

Sign sequences.  I'll show that the computable surreal numbers are precisely the ones with hyperarithmetic sign sequences.  Going from computable surreal notation to hyperarithmetic sign sequence is again an effective transfinite recursion on the rank of the notation.
For the other direction, fix a computable ordinal $\delta$ and some $\emptyset^{(\alpha)}$.  I claim that there is a uniform process that takes a $\beta < \delta$ and a partial $\emptyset^{(\alpha)}$-computable function $f: \beta \to \{+, -\}$ and produces a computable surreal notation $s_f$, such that if $f$ is total then $s_f$ corresponds to the surreal number represented by $f$.  Again this is effective transfinite recursion on $\beta$, but I'll present it as induction.
First, consider the constant $+$ sequence of length $\delta$, and the constant $-$ sequence of length $\delta$.  These serve as bounds for all the sequences we will be considering.  It is straightforward to create computable surreal notations for them, so we can obtain a notation for their difference.  Call it $d$.  Now to the induction.
For $\beta = 0$, this is immediate.
For $\beta > 0$, fix some partial $\emptyset^{(\alpha)}$-computable function $f: \beta \to \{+,-\}$.  We can list all pairs $(\gamma, g)$, where $\gamma < \beta$ and $g$ is a partial $\emptyset^{(\alpha)}$-computable function from $\gamma$ to $\{+,-\}$.  The statement that $f$ and $g$ are both total, that $g$ is an initial segment of $f$, and that $f(\gamma) = +$ is $\Pi^0_2(\emptyset^{(\alpha)})$, so it is $\Sigma^c_{\alpha+3}$.  So using the method described previously, we can make a $b_g$ which is 1 if this is true and 0 if it's false.  Similarly, we make $c_g$ which is for the same statement, except $f(\gamma) = -$.
Now $s_f = \{ s_g - d + b_g\cdot d : (\gamma, g) \ | \ s_g + d - c_g\cdot d : (\gamma, g)\}$.
Note that if $f$ is partial, the left set of $s_f$ consists entirely of negative numbers and its right set entirely of positive numbers, so $s_f$ is a notation for 0.

Fantastic! I was just about to post an update to my answer with a few more arithmetic quantifiers, expecting to get arithmetic at least, but you've gone all the way to hyperarithmetic! This is great.

I guess your superscript $c$ in $\Sigma_\alpha^c$ means that the formula is computably presented, which is important in the argument, since we need the final presentation to be computable.

Yes.  Technically the formulas are defined recursively, where every disjunction or conjunction is over a computable set of formulas.

And not only that, but uniformly computable. The index of the disk/conj are provided by the parent formula.

You mentioned the field operations, but let me remark that your argument here only seems to need the ring operations (that is, addition, subtraction, multiplication), which are effective, which is important since we don't yet seem to know that division is computable.

Your observation on reciprocols is very interesting. I wonder if you can generalize your reals argument to all computable surreals by considering the +- sequence representation? Perhaps the computable surreals are exactly those with a hyperarithmetic +- sequence representation. This is true for reals, and also ordinals. And it would mean the computable reals are a field.

If this is right, I think it would mean that the computable surreals are exactly the surreals in $L_{\omega_1^{CK}}$, which would be very satisfying. Already known to be true for reals and ordinals.

@JoelDavidHamkins Looks like that works.  I've added an argument to my answer.

Fantastic! The corollary is that the computable surreals are indeed a field, indeed a real-closed field, and furthermore they are exactly the surreal numbers of $L_{\omega_1^{CK}}$, which I think is truly very nice.

Dan, it seems that while the result of division $x/y$ is a computable surreal, we don't seem to have division as a computable operation on computable surreals, right? It will be uniform only up to a certain length $\alpha$ of sign sequences, but to go higher you need another algorithm. Right? This makes division a little different from addition, subtraction, multiplication, where we do have uniform computable procedures.

I think we can make it uniform.  From the computable surreal you get a rank, approximately that many jumps can compute the ordering on all the relevant surreals, then you can make the reciprocal hyperarithmetically, convert it to a sign sequence, then back to a computable surreal.  The process to generate the sign sequence also provides a computable notation for the ordinal length.  And the process to convert back was uniform when given $\delta$.

Here is some partial progress. I claim that the computable surreal numbers include some noncomputable real numbers, confirming my guess in connection with question 2.
For each TM program $e$ we can write a program $h_e$ for a computable surreal number, which will have value $0$ if $\varphi_e(e)$ never halts and value $1$ otherwise. Namely, the program $h_e$ simply starts with a default of empty output streams, until such time as it observes $\varphi_e(e)$ to halt, when it places $0$ in the lower set. We can uniformly pass computably from $e$ to the program $h_e$, without knowing the answer to this question.
Let $h$ be the program that places the finite sum $\sum_{e\leq n}h_e2^{-e}$ into the lower set for each $n$ and similarly $(\sum_{e\leq n}h_e2^{-e})+2^{-n}$ into the upper set. That is, for each $e$ we are making the $e$th binary digit $1$ if $e$ halts. The lower set therefore has the supremum (in the reals) of the infinite binary sequence coding the halting problem.
$$\alpha_h = \sum_e h_e2^{-e}$$
The upper set numbers, in contrast, are descending to this real from above, because of the extra $2^{-n}$ term, which exceeds all the rest of the corresponding infinite series.
Note that there is indeed a program $h$ that behaves this way, using the fact that addition is uniformly computable for the computable surreal numbers, and so we can uniformly produce the programs that produce these finite sums, even though we cannot compute the surreal values of the $h_e$ that are involved. Those finite sums are all dyadic rationals, but we don't really know exactly which ones.
The surreal number $\alpha_h$ that $h$ computes is the real number whose binary digits encode the halting problem, which is not a computable real number. And so there are noncomputable real numbers that arise as computable surreal numbers, as desired.
I believe similar methods will ultimately enable us to show that every hyperarithmetic real is a computable surreal number, but I don't quite see my way through the details.
If someone has a nice approach or even just some small further progress, please post an answer.
Update for c.e. reals. Let me explain how the idea adapts to show that every c.e. real arises as a computable surreal number. Suppose that $x$ is a left-c.e. real, which means that there is a computable procedure to enumerate a sequence of rational numbers of which $x$ is the supremum. We may assume that $x$ is irrational. It is not difficult to see that $x=N+\sum_{k\in X}2^{-k}$ for some integer $N$ and c.e. set $X\subseteq\mathbb{N}$.
For each natural number $k$, let $r_k$ be the program whose surreal value is $0$ or $1$, respectively, depending on whether $k\in X$. This program starts with default empty output streams, until it sees $k$ enumerated into $X$, at which time it places $0$ in the lower set, making the resulting surreal value $1$. Now, let $r$ be the program that for each $n$ places $N+\sum_{k\leq n}r_k2^{-k}$ into the lower sets and $(N+\sum_{k\leq n}r_k2^{-k})+2^{-n}$ into the upper sets. So these numbers converge to the value
$$\alpha_r = N+\sum_k r_k2^{-k},$$
which in light of the definition of $r_k$ is the same as the target value $x$. So $x$ is a computable surreal number, as desired.
A similar idea works with right c.e. reals, and so every c.e. real is a computable surreal number. So also are the d.c.e. reals, because we can computably substract.

I recall Michael Rathjen was interested in the compuable aspects of surreal numbers years ago, but gave up on the idea. Still, it might be worth contacting him to see what he came up with.

Perhaps I should clarify that in the expression $h_e2^{-e}$, I intend $h_e$ as the surreal value of that program, but $2^{-e}$ as the dyadic rational with exponent $-e$ taking $e$ as a natural number, the index of a program.

Let me explicate fuller details about the computable surreal number operations. Let's start by showing that they form a ring.
Theorem. The computable surreal numbers form a ring.
Proof. We have to show that the computable surreal numbers are closed under addition, subtraction, and multiplication.
Surreal addition $x+y$ is defined recursively as follows:
$$x+y=\left\{\ x+y_L\quad x_L+y\bigm\vert x+y_R\quad x_R+y\ \right\}.$$
We are using here the usual convention that $x_L$ and $x_R$ range over the left and right sets of $x$, respectively, and similarly for $y$.
It might seem initially unsurmountable to make this computable, since in order to produce the program for $x+y$, we might think that we have to undertake a transfinite recursion in order first to compute $x+y_L$ and so forth.
Nevertheless, I claim that we don't need to mount that recursion. In fact, there is a computable procedure to produce a program realizing $x+y$ as a computable surreal number, given programs for $x$ and $y$. The reason is that by the Kleene recursion theorem, there is a program solving the recursion expressed by the definition of $x+y$. That is, there is a program that takes programs for $x$ and $y$, starts enumerating the left and right sets, and then applies that same addition program to compute the values $x+y_L$, $x_L+y$ and so forth, as the values of $x_L$, $y_L$, $x_R$, $y_R$ are enumerated by $x$ and $y$. So we can computably produce the programs that will exhibit $x+y$ as a computable surreal number.
The same idea works with negation and subtraction
$$\newcommand\unaryminus{-}\unaryminus x=\{\ \unaryminus X_R\mid\unaryminus X_L\ \}.$$
By the notation $\unaryminus X_R$ here we mean the set of all $\unaryminus x_R$ for $x_R\in X_R$, and similarly with $\unaryminus X_L$. Using this, we define subtraction simply as adding the negation:
$$y-x=y+(\unaryminus x).$$
By applying the Kleene recursion theorem, there is a uniform computable procedure to produce $-x$ and $x-y$ from programs for $x$ and $y$.
Similarly with multiplication, which is defined by
$$x\cdot y =\{\ X_{L}\mid X_{R}\ \}\cdot \{\ Y_{L}\mid Y_{R}\ \}=$$
$$=\{\ x_Ly+xy_{L}-x_{L}y_{L}\quad x_{R}y+xy_{R}-x_{R}y_{R}\ \mid\ x_{L}y+xy_{R}-x_{L} y_{R}\quad xy_{L}+x_{R}y-x_{R}y_{L}\ \}$$
By the Kleene recursion theorem, there is a multiplication program that obeys this recursive definition. As numbers get enumerated into the left and right side of $x$ and $y$, we apply that program suitably so as to carry out this definition of $xy$. $\Box$
To get that the computable surreals are a field, we would need division. For reciprocal and division, see the formula on the Wikipedia entry. Notice that for positive $y$ the formula is applied only with positive values of $y_L$, and so we would seem to need to be able to compute the order.
I had posted initially that the order $x<y$ was a c.e. relation, and then argued as a consequence that this was enough to apply the Kleene recursion theorem method to show that division $x/y$ (by nonzero) was computable.
But the c.e. argument was not correct (pointed out by Dan Turetsky in the comments). And so we don't currently know that the computable surreals form a field, and perhaps the evidence is now against this.
See also this related unanswered question of Mike Shulman.
Lastly, regarding saturation, let me prove the following:
Theorem. The order on the computable surreal numbers is computably saturated, in the sense that every c.e. cut is filled. That is,if $X$ and $Y$ are c.e. sets of computable surreal numbers, with every element of $X$ below every element of $Y$, then there is a computable surreal number strictly between.
Proof. This is obvious, since $x=\{\ X\mid Y\ \}$ will be a computable surreal number strictly between, if we have computable enumerations of $X$ and $Y$. $\Box$

Perhaps an idea for computing $\sqrt{x}$ is the standard way of approximating this by division, namely, for each positive $x_L$ we form $x/x_L$ and then compare the result with $x_L$. The larger of these is above $\sqrt{x}$ and the smaller is below $\sqrt{x}$. So we are getting closer to $\sqrt{x}$. And we can recursively also compute $\sqrt{x_R}$ in the same way, and these will be above $\sqrt{x}$. Does this simple idea produce $\sqrt{x}$?

Or what about ${\sqrt{x_L}\mid\sqrt{x_R}}$? If $x>1$, this seemingly has a tighter gap than $x$ itself, so it might equal $\sqrt{x}$? Perhaps that's naive.

That latter naive idea doesn't work correctly for $\sqrt{\omega}$.

But I think the first idea does work for $\sqrt{\omega}$.

IIRC there's a definition for sqrt() in ONAG, though I wouldn't 100% trust it; I'll take a look when I have a chance.

My first idea is also naive, even for $\sqrt{3}$, since $3={2\mid \ }$, but information about $3/2$, $2/3$ and $\sqrt{2}$ will not be enough to determine the cut of $\sqrt{3}$.  So, I don't know how to compute $\sqrt{x}$ in the surreals.

I suppose, of course, that one will need to iterate that approximation idea. (Obviously it is absurd to think it would always work without iteration.) But how long do we iterate? If transfinite, this might take us out of computability.

Speaking of iteration, you might want to ponder on the definition of $1/y$ from Wikipedia again; it's qualitatively different from the definitions for $+$ and $\times$ in that it involves the options to previous approximations of $1/y$. Square root (which I found and will offer up in a new answer) has the same issue.

@StevenStadnicki Ah, yes, you are correct to notice this, but it is no problem for the application of Kleene recursion. The point will be that there is a program that carries out that recursion. Whenever it places something into the left set of $1/y$, then it will also be placing this other updated thing as well, and similarly for the right set. That is a nice way of representing the iteration I was talking about above.

There is an old theorem of Moschovakis (from his Ph.D. thesis I think), that characterizes up to computable isomorphism the structurecomputable reals as the computable field with semidecidable $<$, computable $|{-}|$, computably Cauchy complete and computably archimedean. Which of these properties fails for the computable surreals? It must be the archimedean axiom.

Moschovakis's result ought to be somewhere in this paper, probably around Theorem 5.

It's definitely not Archimedean, since omega is computable (and much more). But also computable surreals are not computable Cauchy complete.

I don't believe your argument that $<$ is c.e..  Another way to have $x < y$ is for $x = y_L$, for some $y_L$ in the left set of $y$.  In fact, my argument about encoding the truth of a sentence $\phi$ into a real would say that $<$ can't be hyperarithmetic.

@DanTuretsky Oh dear, you are right--I have now edited. I should have said $x<y$ iff $x\leq y_L$ or $x_R\leq y$ in some instance, but this isn't enough for the c.e. argument. Do you think that you can use the hyperarithmeticity of $<$ to produce a computable positive surreal whose reciprocol is not computable?

I meant nonhyperarithmeticity. And could you elucidate how you show $x<y$ can't be hyperarithmetic?

Suppose $<$ were $\Sigma^0_\alpha$ for some $\alpha$.  For any $\Sigma^c_\alpha$ sentence $\phi$, we can build the real $b_\phi$ as I described, and this is entirely uniform.  So $\phi$ is true iff $\neg (b_\phi < 1/2)$, which means the truth predict on $\Sigma^c_\alpha$ sentences becomes $\Pi^0_\alpha$, a contradiction.

I edited a bit of discussion about reciprocals into my answer.  Since computable surreals have computable reciprocals inside the reals, I suspect that this remains true in general.  I don't know how to prove it, though.

That is an interesting observation. For the general case, I wonder if it would help to think about the +- sequence representation, which is hyperarithmetic, and try the same trick? Perhaps computable surreal = hyperarithmetic +- sequence? It's true for reals, and also for ordinals.

I think perhaps a transfinite modification of your real argument might show this.

I did indeed find the (or at least a) definition of $\sqrt{x}$ for surreal $x$ in On Numbers And Games (page 22 of the second edition). It looks like this:
$$\sqrt{x}=y=\left\{\sqrt{x^L}, \dfrac{x+y^Ly^R}{y^L+y^R}\right|\left.\sqrt{x^R},\dfrac{x+y^Ly^{L*}}{y^L+y^{L*}}, \dfrac{x+y^Ry^{R*}}{y^R+y^{R*}}\right\}$$
with $x^L$ and $x^R$ the options of $x$ and $y^L$, $y^{L*}$, $y^R$, $y^{R*}$ options of $y$, chosen so that none of the denominators is zero. Note that this builds $y$ in an iterative fashion, using previous options to find new ones. The definition of $\dfrac1x$ does much the same (note that this definition assumes WLOG that $x\gt 0$) :
$$\dfrac1x=y=\left\{0, \dfrac{1+(x^R-x)y^L}{x^R}, \dfrac{1+(x^L-x)y^R}{x^L} \right|\left. \dfrac{1+(x^L-x)y^L}{x^L}, \dfrac{1+(x^R-x)y^R}{x^R}\right\}$$
ONAG's example/explanation for this definition goes something like this: take $x=\{2|\}=3$. Then there is no $x^R$ and the only $x^L$ is 2, so the formula for y becomes $y=\{0, \frac12(1-y^R)|\frac12(1-y^L)\}$. Now, initially we have only $0$ for $y^L$ so the first $y^R$ is $\frac12$; the next $y^L$ is then $\frac12(1-\frac12)=\frac14$, the next $y^R$ is $\frac12(1-\frac14)=\frac38$, etc. It's certainly plausible that the Recursion Theorem still works here to ensure computability, but I'm substantially less sure.

Thanks very much! Yes, the recursion theorem method of my other answer applies here, since there will be a program solving the recursion expressed by the formula. Conclusion:  if $x$ is a computable surreal number, then so is $\sqrt{x}$, and furthermore, there is a uniform computable procedure to compute a program for $\sqrt{x}$ given a program for $x$. Great! (Now, we've just got to do the same thing for solving odd-degree polynomial equations.)

For roots of odd-degree polynomials, can we implement this recursive idea using a surreal version of Newton's method? After all, we have the formal derivative for polynomials.

Does the square root formula generalize easily to $n$th roots?

Sergei Starchenko suggests aiming at the intermediate value theorem as a way to prove real closed. By induction on degree can assume derivative has IVT.

@JoelDavidHamkins I think the biggest difference between square root and general rootfinding is the montonicity; it's very clear e.g. that $\sqrt{x^L}$ is in the left set for $\sqrt{x}$ and $\sqrt{x^R}$ is in the right set, because $x^R\gt x\implies \sqrt{x^R}\gt\sqrt{x}$. You might be able to elide this by using small enough neighborhoods to ensure that $f(x)$ is monotonic on that interval, but I suspect getting there is a little tricky in its own right.

Another issue: since the division argument has now broken (see my answer), we don't know that we can divide computably, and this affects the $\sqrt{x}$ argument. We would no longer know that this is computable.
